# Today vs weeks ago with aggregate function

Tags: sql, database, aggregate-functions, presto

I'm working on the following **presto/sql** query using inline filter to get side by side comparison of current date range vs weeks ago data.

In my case query current date range is `2017-09-13` to `2017-09-14`.

So far I'm able to get the following results, but unfortunately this is not what I want.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 SELECT
        DATE_TRUNC('day',DATE_PARSE(CAST(sample.datep AS VARCHAR),'%Y%m%d')) AS date,
        CAST(SUM(sample.page_views) FILTER (WHERE sample.datep BETWEEN 20170913 AND 20170914) AS DOUBLE) AS page_views,
        CAST(SUM(sample.page_views) FILTER (WHERE sample.datep BETWEEN 20170906 AND 20170907) AS DOUBLE) AS page_views_weeks_ago 
    FROM
        sample 
    WHERE
        (
            datep BETWEEN 20170906 AND 20170914
        ) 
    GROUP BY
        1 
    ORDER BY
        1 ASC 
    LIMIT 50
```

Actual result:

```
+------------+------------+----------------------+
|    date    | page_views | page_views_weeks_ago |
+------------+------------+----------------------+
| 2017-09-06 |          0 |              990,929 |
| 2017-09-07 |          0 |              913,802 |
| 2017-09-08 |          0 |                    0 |
| 2017-09-09 |          0 |                    0 |
| 2017-09-10 |          0 |                    0 |
| 2017-09-11 |          0 |                    0 |
| 2017-09-12 |          0 |                    0 |
| 2017-09-13 |  1,507,715 |                    0 |
| 2017-09-14 |     48,625 |                    0 |
+------------+------------+----------------------+
```

Expected result:

```
+------------+------------+----------------------+
|    date    | page_views | page_views_weeks_ago |
+------------+------------+----------------------+
| 2017-09-13 |  1,507,715 |              990,929 |
| 2017-09-14 |     48,625 |              913,802 |
+------------+------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: why 13th , 14th dates for weeks ago data as it is for 6th and 7th of sep'17

Comment: 13th and 14th are current query date range and I want to get respective week ago data in this case which is 6th (13-7 days) and 7th(14-7 days) respectively.

Comment: hi is you problem got solved

Comment: @sandeeprawat Yes we solved this problem using above SQL and implementing our own custom date lookup algorithm  to replace prior period data to generate expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve with joining a table with itself as a previous day. For brevity, I assume that we have a date field so that date substructions can be done easily.

```
SELECT date,
       SUM(curr.page_views) AS page_views,
       SUM(prev.page_views) AS page_views_weeks_ago 
FROM sample curr
JOIN sample prev ON curr.date - 7 = prev.date
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```